I want to know the space complexity of this function
I was writing this code, and I am confused about whether the space complexity of this question is O(N) or O(N^2).
This is the function whose complexity i want to know:
static pair[] allPairs(int x, int arr1[], int arr2[]) {
    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    Arrays.sort(arr2);
    ArrayList<pair> list=new ArrayList<>();
    int ptr1=0,ptr2=arr2.length-1;
    while(ptr1<arr1.length && ptr2>=0){
        if(arr1[ptr1]+arr2[ptr2]>x){
            ptr2--;
        }
        else if(arr1[ptr1]+arr2[ptr2]<x){
            ptr1++;
        }
        else{
            pair p1=new pair(arr1[ptr1],arr2[ptr2]);
            list.add(p1);
            ptr1++;
            ptr2--;
        }
    }
    return list.toArray(new pair[list.size()]);
}


What is "N" when you say O(N) or O(N^2)? If N is the sum of the lengths of arr1 and arr2, then the space complexity would be O(N).

@BIBOOunit It is O(N*log(N)) because of sorting.

Isnt that time complexity though? OP should be asking for space complexity.

Hey R! It would be a better learning opportunity for you if you could provide your attempt to derive the solution. We can then help point out mistakes (If any) in your reasoning.

Though, I m curious, lets say arr1 is n and arr2 is m and N=n+m. Is O(min(n,m)) valid notation since the number of pairs are bound by the smaller array?

You have two arrays as input, you sort them (I will assume that sorting them does not allocate significant amount of new space) and then you create a new list and then you add pairs derived from your two arrays into the newly created list as many times as the number of such pair-candidates sum to x. So, let's suppose that all the elements of both arrays equates to x / 2, in which case you add all possible pairs, which amounts to a Descartes-product. So, if your first array has M elements and the second array has N elements, then the maximum space you may allocate is M * N elements, so the space complexity is M * N in that edge case. Yet, at a minimum, you allocate 0 elements. Which would mean that you have no pairs in the two arrays that would have a sum of x.
The actual complexity is between the two. Let's say that p is the average number of pairs of an element fulfilling the criteria. If p is small, then the complexity is linear. yet, if p is close to n, then the complexity is O(M * N).
So you will need to analyze this probability/average to properly decide which of the case is true. But at maximum, the complexity is of O(M * N) and you always need to take into account that you will get many matches in some instances.

the space complexity of sorting (Arrays.sort) is typically considered O(log n) in the average case, but it's not a dominant factor here as the focus is on the space used to store the results. finally the space complexity is O(N^2).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
